# Get every pandas dataframe column names separately inside a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and want to extract each column name individually and append it inside a list.

I tried something like this:

```
def get_hist_data(data):
    # create an empty list
    histdata = []
    for col in data.columns:
        test_list = "data['{}']".format(col)
        histdata += [test_list]
    histdata = '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, histdata))

    return histdata
```

and output I got is a list where `data` is a string now:

```
[data['A'], data['B'],data['C']]
```

I don't want `data` as a string but want this as the dataframe which I passed as a parameter of my function `def get_hist_data(data):` and inside of dataframe each column name will be placed.

I want same output which has shown above but `data` won't be a string but a dataframe where every column name will be placed like as `data['A'], data['B']...`

Answer (score 0):

You can access a data frame's column as a list with `df[col].to_list()`

```
def get_hist_data(data):
    histdata = []
    for col in data.columns:
        histdata.append(data[col].to_list())
    return histdata
```

This will return a list of sublists, where each sublist was a column in the original `data`.

Comment: getting output like [[0.20377654359365033, -0.9022193353460645, -1.1331746961471256.....]] but I want [data['A'], data['B'],data['C']]

Comment: I think the issue you're facing is that python can't store representations in that way. You could have `["data['A']", "data['B']","data['C']"]` where each item is a string. But if you want each item in a list to be a reference to a dataframe column, then you'll get that first output. If each list item is a list, then it will expand that list and display the output you are getting: `[[0.203...etc`.

If you could explain more of why you want the data stored in this way, then we may be able to help you. i.e. why is the output you're getting `[[0.203..., ...]] not adequate for your needs?

Comment: It's for plotting those variable in plotly: `hist_data = [df['A'], df['B'], df['C']]
colors = ['#A56CC1', '#A6ACEC', '#63F5EF']
group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
densityPlot = figure_factory.create_distplot(hist_data,
                                             group_labels, colors=colors,
                         bin_size=.2, show_rug=False)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='densityPlot',
        figure=densityPlot
    )
])`

Comment: Did you try the example with the output like [[0.203, -0.902, -1.133],[...]] ? It works for me. Just run what you have with:
`hist_data = get_hist_data(data) # Use the function from my answer`
The confusion is that the example you're reading shows `[df['A'], df['B'], df['C']]`, but when you run this it evaluates to the actual numbers. It is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
histdata = []
for col in data:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[col]) 
    histdata.append(df)

for col in histdata:
    print(col)
```

Here histdata will contain all the dataframes.